# Cannot access Activity public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity

Tags: android, flutter, android-activity, release

The project is not going into a release build. When I try to generate a signed bundle, I get the following error:

```
path_to_activity/MainActivity.java:5: error: cannot access Activity public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {class file for android.app.Activity not found
```

However, in debug mode everything works fine

I tried both through the terminal and through the Android mode, everything is the same. If you go to MainActivity, then there are no errors

Build on ios without error
Thank you!